# Cygwin vim doesn't load files in runtimepath

Tags: vim, cygwin

I created a custom syntax file, and but none of the files in `$VIMRUNTIME` seem to load. I followed these pieces of the documentation:

- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype
- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile

When I do

```
:echo &runtimepath
```

I get:

```
/home/durron597/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/home/durron597/.vim/after
```

However, if I open a file with vim -D, here's the listed files as I type `f`:

```
/etc/vimrc
/home/durron597/.vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

Here's the output of `ls -lR`

```
durron597@Durron597 ~/.vim
$ ls -lR
.:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 durron597 None 0 Jun  3 11:06 ftdetect
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 durron597 None 0 Jun  3 11:06 syntax

./ftdetect:
total 1.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 durron597 None 45 Jun  3 11:06 mytype.vim

./syntax:
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 durron597 None 740 Jun  3 11:06 mytype.vim
```

The exact exact paths are:

```
/home/durron597/.vim/ftdetect/mytype.vim
/home/durron597/.vim/syntax/mytype.vim
```

**Note: the problem is that these files don't seem to be loaded at all, not that these files have internal mistakes**

Output of `:filetype`

```
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF
```

Edit 3: No, really, the files are in the right place:

```
$ find /home -name '*.vim'
/home/durron597/.vim
/home/durron597/.vim/ftdetect/fix.vim
/home/durron597/.vim/syntax/fix.vim
```

Comment: What is the exact path of both `mytype.vim`?

Comment: What is the output of `:filetype` in Vim?

Comment: `$ ls -lR ~` lists the content of your `$HOME`, not of your current directory so, from the information you gave, it looks like those two directories are under `~/`, not `~/.vim/`.

Comment: @romainl that was a typo, somehow it happened when I was changing my username from my real one to durron597. I fixed it. `ls -lR ~` prints out a lot more stuff, I just checked again with no args other than the flags and it prints what I pasted

Comment: @romainl edited again

Comment: Cygwin `vim` is now at 7.4, but this output is from a 7.3 version.  Why?

Comment: @Yaakov Because I haven't updated it recently :-/ but the docs I'm using also are 7.3

Comment: What makes you believe they aren't being loaded? Does it not show up in `:scriptnames`?

Comment: @FDinoff the syntax highlighting doesn't appear, the file doesn't get processed with `vim -D`...

Comment: @durron597 I don't believe `vim -D` is very reliable for this use case. For instance I know of a file that gets during startup but it doesn't show up in the output. It does however show up in the output of `:scriptnames`. Can you post that?

Comment: And just for a sanity check what do you have in `ftdetect/fix.vim` and `syntax/fix.vim`

Comment: @FDinoff, looks like you're correct, it did show up in `:scriptnames`. Which led me to start debugging the right thing, but I still haven't gotten the syntax file to work. But typing `:sy` does make my definitions show up... just nothing turns any colors

Comment: @durron597 if you still can't figure it out I recommend opening a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used `vim -D` but from my testing it doesn't show all the files that get sourced. The place you should be looking is the output of `:scriptnames`.

From the output of `:h scriptnames`

```
                                                :scrip :scriptnames
:scrip[tnames]          List all sourced script names, in the order they were
                        first sourced.  The number is used for the script ID
                        <SID>.
                        {not in Vi} {not available when compiled without the
                        +eval feature}
```

As you can see this is the place where you should have been looking to determine if something was sourced.

From the comments it turns out the file was sourced and something else was the problem.

Comment: I'm on the iOS app I don't think I can give u the bounty until I'm at my comp